# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in application.exe

Tags: c#

```
public object Value
{
    get
    {
        if (this.realDate)
            return (object)base.Value;
        return (object)DBNull.Value;
    }
    set
    {
        if (Convert.IsDBNull(value))
        {
            this.realDate = false;
            this.oldFormat = this.Format;
            this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            this.CustomFormat = " ";
        }
        else
        {
            this.realDate = true;
            // the line below is erroneous 
            this.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
        }
    }
}
```

An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in application.exe i am clueless why this is happening

Comment: What does `return (object)base.Value;` do? My guess is that it's calling the same accessor again. We can't tell without a [mcve] though. And your setter is definitely calling itself for non-null values...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public object Value
{
    …
    set
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

This will essentially call the setter of `Value` again. So you are calling the setter from the setter from the setter from the setter… resulting in an infinite loop which is stopped by the StackOverflowException.

You should have a *backing field* which you write your value to, e.g. something like this:

```
private object _value;

public object Value
{
    get { return _value; }
    set
    {
        // some logic
        _value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: @saqibali You’re welcome! Please remember to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141542) if it solved your problem to mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You have an endless recursive call inside your Value getter:

```
(object)base.Value;
```

Which causes the stackoverflow